# IP Address restriction in IIS7?

Tags: iis-7

I want to restrict users of an IIS7 website to only one user host IP address that I will specify in advance. I've done it the other way round in IIS6, where I restricted a certain domain to see only a special page, everyone else access as normal.

My problem is that I don't know if I can do what I want -- just allow one user host IP or domain. Do you know if this is possible?

I also am unable to find the 'IP Address and Domain Restrictions' dialogs in IIS7. Where did these go?

Comment: You have to add the 'IP Address and Domain Restrictions' Role in the server manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called Address Restriction and should be [easily configured using the Management UI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730889(WS.10).aspx).

Also, the command line can be used to manage restriction rules:

```
appcmd set config /section:ipsecurity /+"[ipaddress='172.16.0.1',allowed='true']"
appcmd set config /section:ipsecurity /+"[ipaddress='172.16.0.0',subnetmask=255.255.0.0',allowed='true']"
appcmd set config /section:ipsecurity /+"[domainname='example.com',allowed='false']"
```